# Python: Populate a large list of string occurences

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of strings:

```
['1 12 4', '2 2 3', '23 32 1', ...]
```

I need to make a list of occurrences for every potential combination:

```
[0, 3, 1, ...]
```

where 1st element is for '1 1 1', second '1 1 2', third '1 1 3' etc. Now if I have list of 5 number strings that range from 1-100, i.e. ['1 2 100 32 99', ...], then that means a potential combination of 100 to the power of 5, which is a pretty big list, especially when most values would be zero.

What is the most efficient way to implement this in Python? The most obvious way that comes to my mind would be to have all combinations and iterate through each and use count in the original list to populate the occurrence list, but I am sure there is a better way.

Comment: I don't understand how you're getting `[0, 3, 1, ...]` from your sample data.

Comment: Just the number of occurrences of that string. So for '1 1 1', it would be myList.count('1 1 1')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to count occurrences of 5-number strings?  Just count them?  The Counter class builds a dictionary of unique values and counts their occurrences from a list:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> s=['1 12 4', '2 2 3', '23 32 1','1 12 4']
>>> Counter(s)
Counter({'1 12 4': 2, '2 2 3': 1, '23 32 1': 1})
```

Comment: A Counter is slightly different to a dictionary. For example using `counter=Counter(s)`, `counter['3 3 3']` would return `0`, despite not in list `s`, whereas a dictionary would throw an exception. (just for completeness)